# HKEY handle is NULL, during debug it writes unused <unable to read memory>

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, registry

I have defined HKEY in anonymous namespace to use it in more cpp. I create register key and it normally returns HKEY, then I want to use that handle in another cpp, and it is NULL. When I debug, it writes unused .

this is one .h file (structAndHandle.h)

```
namespace
{
StCommand command;
HANDLE dataInEvent;
HANDLE dataOutEvent;
HANDLE threadHandle;
HANDLE mutexHandle;
HKEY hKey;
TCHAR repositoryPath[MAX_PATH];
}
```

here I create it... (repositoryStore.cpp)

```
if (RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, STR_KEY_NAME, 0L, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL)
    != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    _tprintf_s(_T("Could not create or open register key: %s\n"), STR_KEY_NAME);
}

TCHAR pathValueName[MAX_PATH] = _T("repositoryPath");
TCHAR indexValueName[MAX_PATH] = _T("repositoryIndex");

TCHAR repPath[MAX_PATH] = _T("C:\\repository\0");
if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, pathValueName, 0L, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)repPath, _tcslen(repPath) * sizeof(TCHAR))
    != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    _tprintf_s(_T("Could not create or set register value: %s\n"), repPath);
}

DWORD repositoryIndex = 0;
if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, indexValueName, 0L, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&repositoryIndex, sizeof(DWORD))
    != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    _tprintf_s(_T("Could not create or set register value: repositoryIndex\n"));
}
```

and when I want to use it here, in another cpp, it is NULL (settings.cpp)

```
DWORD GetDwordSetting(TCHAR* valueName, DWORD defaultValueData)
{
DWORD receivedData;
DWORD type = REG_DWORD;
DWORD size = sizeof(DWORD);
if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, valueName, 0L, &type, (LPBYTE)&receivedData, &size)
    != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    _tprintf_s(_T("Could not get register value: repositoryIndex\n"));
    return defaultValueData;
}
return receivedData;
}

DWORD SetDwordSetting(TCHAR* valueName, DWORD valueData)
{
if (RegSetValueEx(hKey, valueName, 0L, REG_DWORD, (LPBYTE)&valueData, sizeof(DWORD))
    != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    _tprintf_s(_T("Could not set register value: repositoryIndex\n"));
    return GetLastError();
}
return 0;
}

DWORD GetSzSetting(TCHAR* valueName, TCHAR* defaultValueData)
{
DWORD type = REG_SZ;
DWORD size = sizeof(TCHAR) * sizeof(MAX_PATH);
if (RegQueryValueEx(hKey, valueName, 0L, &type, (LPBYTE)&repositoryPath, &size)
    != ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    _tcscpy_s(repositoryPath, defaultValueData);
    _tprintf_s(_T("Could not get register value: repositoryPath\n"));
    return GetLastError();
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are aware, that with an anonymous namespace you'll have instances of these variables that are only seen in the current translation unit? If you set them in one `.cpp`, they'll not interact with the instances in another one.

Comment: So what I can use to interact in various .cpp?

Comment: Parameters in 1st place, global variables as a discouraged solution.

Comment: I cant use parameters, I have to have instance of that handles and struct (those in anonymous namespace) to access them in more .cpp files. for example in that struct are commands, which I send from function to thread

Comment: You can, and should, use parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing your handles in an unnamed namespace put them in a singleton class, that multiple `.cpp` files can access the same instance:

```
class AllMyHandles {
public:
    static AllMyHandles& instance() {
         static AllMyHandles theInstance;
         return theInstance;
    }

    // provide getter setter methods for these handles

private:
    StCommand command;
    HANDLE dataInEvent;
    HANDLE dataOutEvent;
    HANDLE threadHandle;
    HANDLE mutexHandle;
    HKEY hKey;
    TCHAR repositoryPath[MAX_PATH];

    AllMyHandles() {}    
};
```

Another way, is to have a simple class/struct (without the `instance()` function), and to pass instances of these around as reference parameters.